# Template class specialization function call. C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

consider this code.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    public:
      void f(){..}
      void h(){..}
};


template<>
class A<int>
{
    public:
      void f(){// something different..}
      //void h(){..}
};

int main()
{
    A<int> obj;
    obj.h(); // I want to call A<T>::h(), but compiler erred that there is no h function in A<int>
}
```

Is there a way to this call?? Or some workaround?

Comment: The compiler is correct. You can put the `h` function elsewhere, e.g. a base class.

Comment: @Eduard Rostomyan How are you going to call it if it does not exist?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I want to call the commot A<T> :: h(), I dont know how, if I knew I 'd rather ask this question.

Comment: @Eduard Rostomyan By design the specialization A<int> does not have the function. So either you should redesign the templates or shall not call the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A<T>` is a class template that introduces a family of classes `A` based on any typename `T`. `A<int>` is an explicit specialization of `A<T>` - it supersedes the generic class definition. It's no different from having written:

```
class Aint {
public:
    void f(); 
};
```

This specialization only has a single member function - `f`. So when you try to do this:

```
A<int> obj;
obj.h();
```

That doesn't compile because `A<int>` does not have a member function named `h`. Despite both being named `A`, `A<int>` and `A<T>` are unrelated - one is not a base class of the other, and it doesn't matter what functions and members exist in the general `A<T>` - the `A<int>` specialization doesn't have them.

If `h` is something common, you could move it into a base class:

```
struct ABase { // or alternatively ABase<T>
    void h();
}

template <typename T>
class A : ABase {
    void f();
};


template <>
class A<int> : ABase {
    void f();
};
```

That way all of the instantiations of `A` would have an `h()`. That is, until somebody goes ahead and adds:

```
template <>
class A<char> // no inheritance
{
    // no h()
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much stuff you are changing in your specialization, you might be better off just specializing `f` for `A<int>` rather than specializing the entire class:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    public:
      void f(){cout << "standard";}
      void h(){cout << "standard";}
};

template<>
void A<int>::f() {cout << "specialized";}

int main()
{
    A<bool>{}.f(); //outputs standard
    A<int> obj;
    obj.f();       //outputs specialized
    obj.h();       //outputs standard
}
```

If your specialization is more complex than that, you could factor the common behaviour out into a base class and derive `A` from that.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
template<class T>
class BaseA {
public:
  void f(){...}
  void h(){...}
};

template<class T>
class A : public BaseA<T>
{
};


template<>
class A<int> : public BaseA<int>
{
    public:
      void f(){...}
      //void h(){..}
};

int main()
{
    A<int> obj;
    obj.h(); // I want to call A<T>::h(), but compiler erred that there is no h function in A<int>
}
```

It declares a base class which is inherited by both.